# QuickBooks Edit Sequence ID WebConnector

Tags: quickbooks

Situation: I am using a .Net web service connecting to Quickbooks 2012 via the Webconnector calling a web service.

So far the only way I know of getting the Edit Sequence ID/List ID is through a Response when I Operate on the object(Create,Update,Delete)

If my Edit SequenceID/listID get out of synch either my datastore crashes, or they use another webservice to update the object, how do i get it back in synch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, You need to query your object. Once you query it for me it was EmployeeQueryRq

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="12.0"?>
<QBXML>
<QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError"> 
<EmployeeQueryRq requestID = "1">
  <FullName >Smith, Jane H</FullName> 
  </EmployeeQueryRq>
  </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

This presents a potential race condition, in which i can get the Edit Sequence ID but it can be updated and changed before I can get my update in.